# Sort an array based on the sorted order of another array

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, sorting

I have two Array like this:

```
name(0)="jack"
name(1)="nicho"
name(2)="Han"
name(3)="Hugo"

Value(0)="70"
Value(1)="60"
Value(2)="30"
Value(3)="90"
```

How to sort "Name" Based on "Value" sorted position result

result that i want:

```
Value(0)="90"
Value(1)="70"
Value(2)="60"
Value(3)="30"

name(0)="Hugo"
name(1)="jack"
name(2)="nicho"
name(3)="Han"
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I updated my answer to a visual basic example. It creates an array of indexes, sorts the array of indexes according to value() (reverse order), then it reorders both name() and value() according to the now sorted array of indexes().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much more easier when using [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) than two separate arrays

```
Dim val As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
val.Add("jack", 70)
val.Add("nicho", 60)
val.Add("Han", 30)
val.Add("Hugo", 90)
```

and you can sort it like below

```
Dim sorted = From item In val Order By item.Value Descending Select item
```

If you want to add sorted to array

```
        Dim arrName(), arrValue() As String
        Dim k As Integer = 0
        ReDim Preserve arrName(sorted.Count - 1)
        ReDim Preserve arrValue(sorted.Count - 1)
        For Each it In sorted
            arrName(k) = it.Key
            arrValue(k) = it.Value
            k = k + 1
        Next
```

---

---

or

You can do like this

```
        Dim name() As String = {"jack", "nicho", "Han", "Hugo"}
        Dim value() As String = {"70", "60", "30", "90"}

        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim new_value = From val1 In value Order By val1 Descending Select val1
        Dim new_name() As String
        Dim idx As Integer
        ReDim Preserve new_name(new_value.Count - 1)
        For Each itm In new_value
            idx = Array.IndexOf(value, itm)
            new_name(j) = name(idx)
            j = j + 1
        Next
```

This will creates 2 new arrays of `value` and `name` with your desired sort order

[`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vW37Tv)

Comment: Thanks,it Works!. But, how to convert Dictionary Type to Array?

Comment: Your Dictionary is (Of String, String) yet you are adding a string and an integer.  With Option Strict On, this will not compile.  You should use code like this:  `val.Add("jack", "70")`  (note quotation marks around 70).

Answer (score 0):

Generate an array of indexes to value, then sort those indexes according to value. Then reorder value and name in place according to the sorted indexes. This example uses sort with a lambda compare. The reorder in place time complexity is linear O(n), as each array store places an element in it's sorted order. index() will be restored to 0 to length-1.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim name() As String = {"jack", "nicho", "han", "hugo"}
        Dim value() As String = {"70", "60", "30", "90"}
        Dim index(name.Length - 1) As Integer
        Dim i, j, k As Integer
        Dim tname, tvalue As String
        'initialize index
        For i = 0 To name.Length - 1
            index(i) = i
        Next
        'reverse sort index according to value (compare y,x)
        Array.Sort(index, Function(x As Object, y As Object) String.Compare(value(y), value(x)))
        'reorder value and name in place using sorted index
        For i = 0 To name.Length - 1
            If i <> index(i) Then
                tvalue = value(i)
                tname = name(i)
                k = i
                j = index(k)
                While i <> j
                    value(k) = value(j)
                    name(k) = name(j)
                    index(k) = k
                    k = j
                    j = index(k)
                End While
                value(k) = tvalue
                name(k) = tname
                index(k) = k
            End If
        Next
        For i = 0 To name.Length - 1
            Console.WriteLine(name(i) + ControlChars.Tab + value(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```